# Does modifying the value of a "boxed" variable of the dynamic type create an implicit copy?

Tags: c#, dynamic, struct, reference

I thought of this when I read that C#'s `dynamic` is actually a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

So I whipped up something like this:

```
struct ValueType
{
    public int test;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void modifier(dynamic variable)
    {
        variable.test = 10;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ValueType valTypeVar = new ValueType();
        valTypeVar.test = 1;
        System.Console.WriteLine(valTypeVar.test);
        modifier(valTypeVar);
        System.Console.WriteLine(valTypeVar.test);
    }
}
```

This prints

```
1
1
```

while I expected it to print

```
1
10
```

Why doesn't the code above work as expected? The variable has definitely been boxed, so there is no way that `variable.test = 10;` would get evaluated as `( (ValueType)variable ).test`. What's going on behind the scenes? Does `variable` get implicitly copied to a new variable instance which is then modified? If so, does it also happen when it is passed a `class` reference type?

Also, if the above is true, why is `dynamic` considered a reference type when it actually seems to take on the semantics of value types and reference types at will, i.e. can be either value-type or reference-type? Isn't the fact that it is passed to methods by reference then just an implementation detail?

Comment: Not sure, but here's my guess--`dynamic` is an illusion.  It hides the fact from you *and* the compiler of what is actually happening until *it actually does*.  So, at runtime, everything is bound and validated, and you are not sending a dynamic through to the method but the actual value type.  So it behaves as any normal value type would in this circumstance. Let's see if I'm right.

Comment: *dynamic* is syntax sugar for System.Object.  It doesn't otherwise make value types behave differently, they still get boxed and your code is still only updating the boxed copy.  This code can only work if you use *class*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `modifier` you are indeed boxing `valTypeVar`.  You are then mutating that boxed value.

The fact that you copied the value of `valTypeVar` into a boxed value and mutated that boxed value of course won't mutate the value in `valTypeVar`.